# IPC between Node.js and Arduino Sketch on Intel Galileo

Tags: node.js, arduino, ipc, communication, intel-galileo

I want to communicate between a **Node.js** server and an **Arduino Sketch**. I discovered that there are three ways to do it:

1. Files
2. UDP
3. IPC

I can probably implement files, but I need to read sensor values and send them to **Node.js**, and this seems slow and will reduce the life of SD card.

I have found one [some instructions](https://communities.intel.com/message/209562) for UDP and an [IPC implementation](http://www.instructables.com/id/EE6W2JJHNTTE3IA/?lang=entre). I want to implement the same with Node.js. How do I do it?

This is one of THE tasks that Galileo must perform. I was surprised to see so little support for it